# Why doesn't my map work? It's just purple and black everywhere

Tags: garrys-mod

I wonder why my maps is just purple and black? How can I fix/download something so that I can play on them, not just see bugged floor and purple and black. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to Garry's Mod errors, purple/black means you're missing textures for the objects and giant red ERROR means you're missing the object itself.

What this essentially means is that you do not have the game installed that the texture comes from.

There are other methods to fix this issue which include changing the DirectX levels, but this can cause more issues than good.

Comment: so if i download a deathrun map that is from css that means i need the css game to get rid of the error Things?

Comment: @bacca yes, CS:S is pretty much a requirement for garry's mod gamemodes like TTT

Comment: @bacca there are also download links and youtube guides for downloading the textures in case you don't own CS:S